# Question about slash commands in discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js, replit

I want to make a Discord bot that can react to the slash commands and "type" commands. To prevent naming collisions, I renamed the `command` variable into `scommand`. However, when I do this, the code of slash command doesn't work. How can I fix it?

discord.js version: 12.5.3

```js
const { REST } = require('@discordjs/rest');
const { Routes } = require('discord-api-types/v9');
const {Collection} = require("discord.js")
const scommands = [];
const scommandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./slash.commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
client.scommands = new Collection();

const clientId = process.env["clientId"]

for (const file of scommandFiles) {
  try {
    const scommand = require(`./slash.commands/${file}`);
    scommands.push(scommand.data.toJSON());
    client.scommands.set(scommand.data.name, scommand)
  } catch (err) {console.log(err)}
}

const rest = new REST({ version: '10' }).setToken(token);

(async () => {
        console.log('Started refreshing application (/) commands.');

        await rest.put(
            Routes.applicationCommands(clientId),
            { body: scommands },
        );

        console.log('Successfully reloaded application (/) commands.');
})();

client.ws.on('INTERACTION_CREATE', async interaction => {
    if (!interaction.isChatInputCommand()) return;

    const command = client.scommands.get(interaction.commandName);

    if (!command) return;

    try {
        await command.execute(interaction);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        await interaction.reply({ content: 'There was an error while executing this command!', ephemeral: true });
    }
});
```

This is the code of the file in the `./slash.commands` folder:

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');
module.exports = {
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('ping')
    .setDescription('pong'),
    async execute(interaction){
interaction.reply("pong")
}
```

Is it ok to use `scommand` and how should I fix it?

Comment: What do you mean by "the code doesn't work"? Do you get any error messages or unexpected behavior?

Comment: It said 
"The application did not respond"

Comment: Any useful logs? I see in your code a bunch of `console.log()`.

Comment: Where is `client` defined?

Comment: those log are just for my reference:
`Started refreshing application (/) commands.
(node:7868) ExperimentalWarning: stream/web is an experimental feature. This feature could change at any time
(Use node --trace-warnings ... to show where the warning was created)
Successfully reloaded application (/) commands.
Bot is ready!
Connected to MongoDB
`

Comment: The client:
`const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits] });`

Comment: Are you trying to use `GatewayIntentBits` in discord.js v12.5.3? It will be `undefined` and if you pass it to the client, the `interactionCreate` event won't fire.

Comment: oh then should i remove it or change to other stuff?

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me, you declared a `scommands` field in `client`, but when executing, you refer to it as `commands`...

Try:

```
const command = client.scommands.get(interaction.commandName);
```

Comment: ty i changed but still not working